# Rails HTML editor to create forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a HTML editor which can be (easiliy) integrated in a RoR app that has the possibility to create forms.
Not forms per se, but I need the possibility to add radiobuttons, input fields, checkboxes and so on.
I loved the smoothness of TinyMCE, but apparently this doesn't take me far enough.
Does there exists such a gem/plugin?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have FCKeditor and this brother CKeditor.

The plugin FCKEditor is easy to integrate in Rails

- [fckeditor plugin](http://blog.caronsoftware.com/2006/08/07/fckeditor-plugin-for-rails/)

About CKeditor, it's integrate in [Typo](http://github.com/fdv/typo), but we don't extract some plugin

Comment: Looks good, but are all the possibilities somewhere listed so i know all my components I will need are included?